# Adjacent circles with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, geometry, css, css-shapes

I wonder if it's possible, and if so - how, to draw adjacent circles as seen on the image below with HTML and CSS?

[image]

Comment: Put them in a container with positioning.

Comment: What type of elements should I use? A `div` would render squares, even if `border-radius` is simplied, wouldn't it?

Comment: Just remember, no matter if you are using images or css to make something look like a circle, the space that element it's using it's still a box or rectangle. But what you are asking its possible in way. It can be done with just css and with css and jquery as well. It will require some time to do, but yes, its possible. if you want I could come up with a demo

Comment: @Allan So an element will *always* be a square? I assume that the trick is to use something like absolute positioning, opacity (on the area surrounding the circle) and different z-index?

Comment: If you use just css, you will need to define the position for each element manually. With JQuery you could assign the possition dynamically by just assigning the area available, the size for each circle with maybe their radius.

Comment: @Numbers, yes, position absolute will be needed, but not opacity.

Comment: @Numbers, do you want this to be static content, or dynamic content?

Comment: I'd like it to be dynamic.

Comment: It can't be dynamic with just HTML and CSS. If you wanted it to be dynamic, you'd have to do some math with Javascript to make sure none of the circles intersect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try like this:

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RV5b4/199/)**(*Added few more circles to make it more interesting*)

**CSS**

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

#circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#small-circle{
  margin-top: 25%;
  margin-left: 45.5%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 50%;
}#smallest-circle{
  margin-top: 55%;
  margin-left: 78%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: #f00;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="circle">
  </div>
    <div id="small-circle">
      </div>
    <div id="smallest-circle">
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I loved this one. This is responsive too. One question though. What is the advantage of "margin-left" instead of just "left"? Same with "top". Might be silly. But highly appreciate your answer.

Comment: @ThomasSebastian:- The simplest way I can explain it is that margin-left moves the element itself, whereas left pushes other elements away. No other reason. :)

Comment: OMG, nice one! but it's with static content, but still really good!

Answer (score 2):

Sure! Create some divs, each with `position:absolute` and a width and height of 0. Then apply a border and border radius to each one, and position them by trial and error.

[**here's a sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/78cf6Lda/)

HTML

```
<div class="circle c1"> </div>
<div class="circle c2"> </div>
<div class="circle c3"> </div>
<div class="circle c4"> </div>
```

CSS

```
.circle {
    position:absolute;
    width:0;
    height:0;
}

.c1 {
    left:100px;
    top:100px;
    border:50px solid red;
    border-radius:50px;
}
.c2 {
    left:118px;
    top:185px;
    border:100px solid blue;
    border-radius:100px;
}

.c3 {
    left:300px;
    top:70px;
    border:125px solid green;
    border-radius:125px;
}

.c4 {
    left:295px;
    top:310px;
    border:65px solid yellow;
    border-radius:65px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the `<canvas>` tag, implemented in HTML5.  It requires a bit of Javascript to draw the circles, but gives you a lot of power.  Here is a basic mock-up of your sample image:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="1000"> <!--style="border:1px solid #000000;"-->
</canvas> 

<script>
/* Identify the Canvas object */
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); 
/*Built-in HTML5 object that allows for drawing*/
var c1y = c.getContext("2d");
/* Set your fill and stroke color */
c1y.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
c1y.strokeStyle = "#FFFF00";
/*Draw the circle.
Arc property: arc(x,y,r,start,stop) */
c1y.beginPath();
c1y.arc(100,80,80,0,2*Math.PI);
/* Applies the stroke and fill to the drawn circle */
c1y.stroke();
c1y.fill();

var c2o = c.getContext("2d");
c2o.fillStyle = "#FF6600";
c2o.strokeStyle = "#FF6600";
c2o.beginPath();
c2o.arc(220,40,40,0,2*Math.PI);
c2o.stroke();
c2o.fill();

var c3p = c.getContext("2d");
c3p.fillStyle = "#6600FF";
c3p.strokeStyle = "#6600FF";
c3p.beginPath();
c3p.arc(320,60,60,0,2*Math.PI);
c3p.stroke();
c3p.fill();

var c4g = c.getContext("2d");
c4g.fillStyle = "#66FF99";
c4g.strokeStyle = "#66FF99";
c4g.beginPath();
c4g.arc(450,120,80,0,2*Math.PI);
c4g.stroke();
c4g.fill();

var c5b = c.getContext("2d");
c5b.fillStyle = "#3399FF";
c5b.strokeStyle = "#3399FF";
c5b.beginPath();
c5b.arc(240,190,95,0,2*Math.PI);
c5b.stroke();
c5b.fill();

var c6y = c.getContext("2d");
c6y.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
c6y.strokeStyle = "#FFFF00";
c6y.beginPath();
c6y.arc(410,305,105,0,2*Math.PI);
c6y.stroke();
c6y.fill();

var c7o = c.getContext("2d");
c7o.fillStyle = "#FF6600";
c7o.strokeStyle = "#FF6600";
c7o.beginPath();
c7o.arc(80,220,60,0,2*Math.PI);
c7o.stroke();
c7o.fill();

</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

For reference, check out: [http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp]

Answer (score 1):

Here is mine -  [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/haware/2/edit)  ,
**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="cir_1"></div>
  <div class="cir_2"></div>
  <div class="cir_3"></div>
  <div class="cir_4"></div>
  <div class="cir_5"></div>
  <div class="cir_6"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
}
.cir_1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius : 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
.cir_2 {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background: orange;
  border-radius : 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 101px;
  top: 2px;
}
.cir_3 {
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  background: purple;
  border-radius : 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 169px;
  top: 15px;
}
.cir_4 {
  height: 110px;
  width: 110px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius : 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
  top: 81px;
}
```